# Control Quartz.net server remotely

Tags: .net, sql, quartz.net

I'm going to setup a Quartz.net server as a Windows Service and setup and schedule jobs using ADO Job Store. However, once in production I will have no access to the Win Svc.  I want to create a web page that stores simple commands in a SQL table. Then have a job pickup those commands and carry them out on the Quartz server. I've done this with some homegrown Win Svcs and it works great.

So for example I have commands like Hard Stop, Pause, Unpause, Reload Config.  I want to be able to do these things AND log the actions but for my Quartz server.

Is this feasible? Is there a better way to go about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears [Crystal Quartz Panel](https://github.com/guryanovev/CrystalQuartz) does some of what I'm looking for.